# DapperPlus BulkMerge Infromation about insert/update

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, dapper

I am trying to get some information after successful BulkMerge operation.
I want to know, how many rows are updated and how many are inserted.
I was trying with Transaction but had no luck with that.

My code :

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            Connection.BulkMerge(compUsers);
            transactionScope.Complete();
            var x = transactionScope;
        }
```

compUsers is list with data that will be inserted/updated. But I have no idea how to get some relevant information about this transaction. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible.

As explained by JonathanMagnan on this link.
https://github.com/zzzprojects/Dapper-Plus/issues/34

Comment: ideally can you include the important parts from the link as well? link only answers are not very helpful if the link dies